# I cannot understand this DecimalToBinary recursive function

Tags: python, function, binary

I found this code but I can't understand this:

```
def DecimalToBinary(num):
    if num >= 1:
        DecimalToBinary(num // 2)
    print(num % 2, end = '')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dec_val = 24
    DecimalToBinary(dec_val)
```

Comment: Try to run it https://pythontutor.com/ - and see each step-by-step execution.  Try with small number - eg. 6 first.

Comment: I tried to explain the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72799650/16177121)

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you can run this code in such a visual platform first - https://pythontutor.com/  and see each step execution.

But this recursive function just did these two/three things:

```
if num >= 1:                      # if num is greater or equal to 1: do next
    DecimalToBinary(num // 2) # recusive call -> put this new num // 2
                                  # 6 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0  eg. starting with 6 and go to next loop/recursive call.  Temp. result is stored in `stack` for later

print(num % 2, end = '')      # now it's out of the loop (all done - reaching 0), so we check if this num's remainder  by module (%) - and get 0 or 1 and start to return it as 0 or 1. As such we got -> 0110 as the final output.
```

output

```
0110
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive code. You pass the number to the function till it is not grater than 1, and since you have to print the binary of decimal which is in reverse order you have added print statement after the function call. The call for the function is a call by value and does not update the number.

Answer (score 0):

Before understanding code let's understand how decimal to binary conversion is done using pen and paper.

### Example: Convert 8 to binary

1. Divide 8 by 2 and note the remainder & quotient.
2. Now, divide the obtained quotient by 2 and note the remainder & quotient.
3. Repeat the steps until the quotient is not equal to 0
4. Now, write all the obtained remainders in the reverse order
5. The sequence you obtain will be the output.

```
On dividing 8/2: quotient = 4
                 remainder = 0

On dividing 4/2: quotient = 2
                 remainder = 0

On dividing 2/2: quotient = 1
                 remainder = 0

On dividing 1/2: quotient = 0
                 remainder = 1

remainders = 0 0 0 1
output = 1 0 0 0
```

**Now that you know how decimal to binary conversion works it's time to understand how the working of the code.**

### Code Working

Let's take the same example of converting 8 to a binary number. So `dec_value = 8`

1. function `DecimalToBinary` called with `8` passed as argument.
2. The first statement `if num >= 1` will make a recursive call to `DecimalToBinary` if the statement is true otherwise it will print the remainder of num obtained by dividing num by 2 using `num % 2`

**On every recursive call**
The function calls are stored in memory in stack so that they can be called again after the termination of the recursive call the function call is popped out of the stack to execute the remaining code.

```
num = 8: DecimalToBinary(8)                 // func stored in stack
         if 8 >= 1 -> true
         call DecimalToBinary(4)

num = 4: DecimalToBinary(4)                 // func stored in stack
         if 4 >= 1 -> true
         call DecimalToBinary(2)

num = 2: DecimalToBinary(2)                 // func stored in stack
         if 2 >= 1 -> true
         call DecimalToBinary(2)

num = 1: DecimalToBinary(1)                 // func stored in stack
         if 1 >= 1 -> true
         call DecimalToBinary(0)

num = 0: DecimalToBinary(0)                 // recursive call terminated
         if 0 >= 1 -> false
         print 0 % 2, i.e. 0)               // 0
```

now the function will be popped from the stack one by one in LIFO order. *remember: how output is reverse of remainders we get*

```
num = 8: DecimalToBinary(1)
         print 1 % 2, i.e. 0)               // 0 1

num = 4: DecimalToBinary(2)
         print 2 % 2, i.e. 0)               // 0 1 0

num = 2: DecimalToBinary(4)
         print 4 % 2, i.e. 0)               // 0 1 0 0

num = 1: DecimalToBinary(1)
         print 8 % 2, i.e. 0)               // 0 1 0 0 0
```